# how to get complete memory stats for a qiskit circuit

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime, memory-space

I am interested in running several qiskit circuits on multiple GPUs and record their memory usage. My issue is when circuit runs successfully I am unable to get exact amount of memory it took during execution. Or is there any way to pre-calculate amount of memory required by the circuit before its actual execution.

In this context I would like to get explanation of following parameters in result object:

```
required_memory_mb 
memory_slots
```